# Can I pass an imported local image file into an object?

Tags: reactjs

I have an imported image file and I want to pass it into an object that is called in my app return:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import Gallery from '../Gallery';

import About from '../imgs/work-one/about.jpg';

const IMAGES = [
  {
    src: WorkOne.About
  }
]

class WorkOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
       <Gallery images={IMAGES} />
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default WorkOne
```

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I removed 'WorkOne.' from 'WorkOne.About' and it worked!

Comment: Is this an image file link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import Gallery from '../Gallery';

import About from '../imgs/work-one/about.jpg';

const IMAGES = [
  {
    src: About
  }
]

class WorkOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
       <Gallery images={IMAGES} />
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default WorkOne
```